# Do we need to lock when we get the property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, thread-safety, automatic-properties

In C#, is it necessary to lock when getting a non volatile property? I know we need to lock when setting the property.  how about getting?

Now 3.0 provide automatic property, is it thread safe itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are C# auto-implemented static properties thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074670/are-c-auto-implemented-static-properties-thread-safe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) are not thread-safe. They are nothing more than syntactic sugar; the compiler automatically generates the private backing fields, just as if you'd written them out manually.

However, unless your application is accessing properties from multiple threads, there's no reason to worry about this in the first place. It's hard to tell from your question if your app is multi-threaded.

Comment: I think that an automatic property is always thread safe, since it is only the return statement. (if the propertyt type is a struct I am not so sure...). However, I think, that you have to be careful, since what you return from a property is in no way secured against concurrency in any way.

Comment: @Mario: Automatic properties are not "only the return statement". They also include a setter, which is not thread safe for obvious reasons. But even a getter is not *necessarily* thread-safe.

Comment: ok, depends on the data type, everything that can be atomically manipulated is thread safe though (so only monsters like doubles or floats come to my mind right now) - again I haven't made up my mind about struct...

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If multiple threads are reading/writing to the same property, you will have to lock it.

Automatic properties are nothing more than syntactic sugar and don't lock.

Answer (score 2):

No. You still need to lock if you're accessing the property from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that depends on the type of the property. If it can be read atomically (like an int or a pointer) than the read is safe.

However if you access an object through a property, then multiple threads can access that object simultaneously.

but a lock in the getter/ setter wouldn't help here either.